# DJANGO Jquery/ajax get 'httpresponse' JSON

Tags: ajax, django, json, jquery

I have been picking away at this, though thought I would reach out for some advice, if I may, I am fairly new to AJAX.

Right, I am using the django framework, I post the data to the server, which works great, then receive some data back on the callback function, which works, though I want this to be in JSON format so I can populate a table. Currently it either renders in plain text or the browser asks me to download the json data, meaning somethings not quite catching on the $.get part. My code is:

```
  #views.py

  if request.POST:
  est_show = login_a.test()
  return HttpResponse(est_show, content_type='application/json')


     <!--JQUERY/AJAX-->
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("submit","#these_choices",function (event) {
     var data_form = $('#these_choices').serialize();


   if(data_form) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url Create_this %}",
      data: {'test':'test','csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      cache:false,
      success: function(){
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $.get('{% url Create_this %}', function(data) {
            alert(data[0]);
          });});

                },
      error: function(){
        alert('error !!!!');
      }

              });}
else {
  alert('error elsewhere');
}

 event.defaultPrevented(); //not running PreventDefault returns json using defaultPrevented returns json and doesnt render anything when this is blanked out...
 return false;
  });
  </script>
```

It also seems the alert(data[0]) is being ran before the json data is being received in the browser. Any advice will be appreciated?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `mimetype` in the `HttpResponse` to `application/json`.  When you don't specify a `dataType` in the ajax request, JQuery automatically tries to infer it based on the mimetype of the response.

```
return HttpResponse(est_show, mimetype='application/json')
```

Alternatively, you can set the `dataType` to `json` to tell JQuery to expect json.